# PHP Explode() get strings after the last PERIOD (.)

Tags: php, explode

i hope someone can help me.

I have this string for example:

```
But the LORD is in His holy temple. Let all the earth be silent before Him. Habakkuk 2:20
```

I want to use explode function to get the last part string "Habakkuk 2:20", my problem is how to tell to explode function to choose the last period (.) of the string?

Comment: [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Explode returns the array of strings split on the period character. So if you know you want the last one: $arr = explode($str,'.'); $lastPart = $arr[count($arr)-1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need explode here. You can find the position of the last period using the `strrpos` function and get everything after that pos:

```
$str = 'But the LORD is in His holy temple. Let all the earth be silent before Him. Habakkuk 2:20';
$pos = strrpos($str, '.');
echo substr($str, $pos+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this.

```
$str = 'But the LORD is in His holy temple. Let all the earth be silent before Him. Habakkuk 2:20';
$arr = explode('.',$str);
echo end ($arr);
```

Comment: use trim() if you want to remove empty space around the string. Ex. echo trim(end ($arr));